# Why error is being logged as info in GCP when using fastify logging?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, fastify

We have configured Fastify to log as info using the following:

```
const fastify = require("fastify")({
  logger: { level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || "info" }
});
```

and from our Error handler we are logging every error as:

```
fastify.setErrorHandler(async (error, request, reply) => {
    request.log.error(error);
});
```

But logs in GCP are being logged as info.

Bonus: JSON logs are being separated by line, I guess is for the use of Pino and NDJSON.

Thanks

Comment: could you add some screen example of the logs?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I can add some screen but I don't see how that can help. I would have to mask many things in those logs because is confidential. My question is more general as I think that many people should have this problem or I have configured something wrong

Comment: Could you add some screen? I would check if the log.error print to stdout or stderr stream